# Symfony Single Login Form Handling Multiple User Types

Tags: symfony

Consider a single login form that relates to a single entity for the login, and checks the credentials.

How would I go about having a single login form that handles four user type accounts?

Two user types are usernames and two user types are emails.

The way I came up with is just checking if the input for the username is a username or email to narrow the selection field down to only two user types and then running the login query to get the users details for one user type.

Then if nothing is found, run a second query for the second user type that the information could be connected to.

Return errors if none, and if so, then log the user in.

But as I'm new to Symfony, do you have any tips of how I would go about doing this correctly with the framework?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad for this forum. It would be helpful if you could provide code for something you have tried and then identify a specific problem you are having. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom User Provider as described in Symfony docs:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html

A simple example is provided on the site. You can implement your idea in `fetchUser()` method.

```
<?php

namespace App\Security\User;

// use...

class WebserviceUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    // ...

    private function fetchUser($username)
    {
        // Your logic

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way of editing what providers are used for what login form and when. Like a way under the login_form in security.yaml. Because all providers I have now work for all entities, I just need a way I can configure the login_form to work with all the providers instead of just working with one specific provider. Thanks for your time.

Comment: How would you want to decide which user provider is responsible for fetching the user? One way is to configure a chain provider that would just try one provider after the other until one provider is able to find the user. But if there are other criteria to do the selection of the proper provider, you could implement a custom one that gets the other injected and delegates the calls based on these criteria to the provider that is actually responsible.